# Location address validation in android

Tags: android, android-maps

I just wanna validate location address in android.I've an EditText.if i enter an location address(like sanjose,US 9746),i need to check this is valid one or not.I think it is possible using google map.But i donno how could to check whether the typed address is valid?Any examples are much appreciatable.

Thanks.

Comment: using Google services address lookup service is not possible you can use [melissadata](www.melissadata.com) or [usps](www.usps.com) for address verification

Comment: @imran khan how could i implement this in android coding? Does it provide any api for android?